# NSMutableArrays are null

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsviewcontroller

I have an NSViewController subclass with:

```
@property (retain) NSMutableArray* entities;
@property (retain) NSMutableArray* tiles;
```

In my `-init` method, both arrays are created with `+new`, and are given one object each. After that, I call `NSLog(@"%@, %@", entities, tiles);`, and it gives me just as expected:

```
2012-12-30 15:07:04.160 Project Land III[2177:303] (
"<RBEntity: 0x100508170>"
), (
"<RBTile: 0x100508470>"
)
```

I can click a button on the view, though, which calls the same log function, and it spit out this:

```
2012-12-30 15:07:06.071 Project Land III[2177:303] (null), (null)
```

I've been stuck on this problem in some form or another for days. Why in the world are the arrays null?

I'm more than happy to post more code, just let me know!

Interface:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "RBEntity.h"
#import "RBTile.h"

@interface RBMainViewController : NSViewController {
    NSMutableArray* _entities;
    NSMutableArray* _tiles;
}

@property (retain) NSMutableArray* entities;
@property (retain) NSMutableArray* tiles;

- (IBAction)log:(id)sender;

@end
```

My `-init` method:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    self.entities = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.tiles = [NSMutableArray new];
    [self.entities addObject:[RBEntity entityWithLocation:NSMakePoint(4, 5) type:FACEEATER]];
    [self.tiles addObject:[RBTile tileWithLocation:NSMakePoint(10, 2) type:GRASS]];
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", self.entities, self.tiles);
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your interface code for this class?

Comment: I can see you don't have [super init]..

Answer (score 1):

> In my `-init` method, both arrays are created with `+new`, and are given one object each. After that, I call `NSLog(@"%@, %@", entities, tiles);`, and it gives me just as expected:
>
> ```
> 2012-12-30 15:07:04.160 Project Land III[2177:303] (
>     "<RBEntity: 0x100508170>"
> ), (
>     "<RBTile: 0x100508470>"
> )
> ```
>
> I can click a button on the view, though, which calls the same log function, and it spit out this:
>
> ```
> 2012-12-30 15:07:06.071 Project Land III[2177:303] (null), (null)
> ```

This is a very common novice mistake.

You have *two* RBMainViewController objects. One of them, you presumably created in code in one of your other .m files, by saying something like `[[RBMainViewController alloc] init]`. The other, you created in a nib, probably by dragging it into the nib.

(Note: The nib that you created that VC in is *not* the VC's nib. That would be circular, to have the VC's nib containing the VC that is loading the nib. The VC that doesn't have its arrays resides in nib A, and each VC will load nib B.)

The VC that you created in a nib is the one whose view appears on the screen. Because that object never received an `init` message (it was initialized with some other `initWith…` message instead), you never created its arrays. The view controller you created with `init`, which does have its arrays, is not visible on the screen (otherwise you would have clicked on its button, rather than the other's, and you'd have seen the arrays in the output).

The solution involves two changes.

The first is to change your implementation of `init` to be an implementation of `initWithNibName:bundle:` instead. Like so:

```
- (instancetype) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName
    bundle:(NSBundle *)bundle
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:bundle];
    if (self != nil) {
        <#...#>
    }
    return self;
}
```

If you want to continue using `init` to create your VC in other code, fine, but your implementation of `-[RBMainViewController init]` should simply send `initWithNibName:bundle:` to `self` and return the result.

```
- (instancetype) init {
    return [self initWithNibName:<#nibName#> bundle:<#bundle#>];
}
```

You also need to delete one of the two view controllers. We'd need to see the code and the nib to know which. If you delete the one you created in code, you may want to create an outlet in that class and connect it in the nib. If you delete the one in the nib, any outlet connections you established in that nib to that VC, you'll need to re-create in code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to use `self.entites` and `self.tiles` when working with those objects in your class.

**EDIT (after interface added)**

You will need to have something in your interface like:

```
@interface RBMainViewController : NSViewController{
    NSMutableArray* _entities;
    NSMutableArray* _tiles;
}

@property (retain) NSMutableArray* entities;
@property (retain) NSMutableArray* tiles;

- (IBAction)log:(id)sender;

@end
```

Then you will need to add this to the implementation:

```
@synthesize entities = _entities;
@synthesize tiles = _tiles;
```

Comment: for both setting and getting?

Comment: Yes. I'll post my `-init` method.

Comment: Why would accessing the instance variables directly cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom getter/setter for one of these properties, and put a breakpoint there to see who's resetting the value. If that doesn't catch the problem, and your property is still being reset, you're probably accessing them from an instance of your `NSViewController` that hasn't been initialised by your `init`, thus those properties were always uninitialised.

Comment: There seems to be some sort of infinite loop going on.

Comment: @Riley with the custom setter? If yes, you're probably assigning the value to the property itself, causing an infinite recursion on the setter. You need to `@synthesize entities = _entities`, and let its setter change the value of `_entities`, while the getter returns `_entities`. Also, as noted by @pbibergal, you're not calling `[super init]` in your `init`.

Comment: Infinite recursion fixed, thank you. I'm now calling `self = [super init];` at the beginning of the `init` method. According to the log, there is something setting both arrays to null. How would you recommend I track down that object?

Comment: @Riley perhaps by putting a conditional breakpoint on `objc_msgSend()` when either of the arrays is `nil`, then printing a stack trace. This way you'll know that which is the method **before** which they're set to `nil`.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on that log call, and look at the stack trace to see who is calling your setter with the null value.

Comment: @H2CO3 You're a bit over my head. I know how to set a condition and an action through the breakpoint navigator, but what exactly would I put? I've never used a conditional breakpoint before.

Comment: @jweyrich Thread 1 gives me this:  0 `-[RBMainViewController setEntities:]`  1 `-[RBMainViewController init]`  2 `-[RBAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:]`

Comment: @Riley I'm not sure what kind of answer do you expect since I'm not using Xcode, but in GDB, I'd write `break objc_msgSend if array1 == nil || array2 == nil`

Comment: @H2CO3 Thank you for tolerating my ignorance! I added to the code `if (e == nil) return;` and `if (t == nil) return;` before the actual setting, the arrays are still null when I click the button.

Comment: @H2CO3 Edit: I have the condition `(NSMutableArray*)e == nil || e == NULL` set, and it completely skips the breakpoint.

Comment: @Riley To the console, type what I wrote, then re-run the app.

Comment: Apparently `breakpoint objc_msgSend` is an invalid command in lldb.

Comment: @H2CO3 okay, I think I've figured the equivalent command in lldb.

Comment: @Riley Cool. Hope that'll get you a bit further.

Comment: @Riley: If your breakpoint is not being hit within the condition, then nothing is changing your properties to null. As I mentioned in my answer, you're probably accessing 2 distinct instances of your controller. One initialised by `init`, and other by `initWith...`. To find if that's the real cause, print the value of `self` during `init`, and also on your button's action. Then compare the 2 outputs to see if they match. If they don't, then you have 2 instances of your controller, and (as your stack-trace reveals) you should not call `[RBMainViewController init]` from your AppDelegate.